# Is there any way to detect whether a device has a case and screen protector on it?

Tags: ios, screen, protector

I know this might be a stupid question, but can we detect whether an iPhone device has a case and screen protector on it in code?

Answer (score 4):

Enable the microphone and then vibrate the device. If you have a baseline idea of how the audio frequency looks without a bumper, then you can diff that against what you record.

Typically, the cases are made out of materials like silicone that reduce the intensity of the vibration sound.

Comment: Interesting idea, I imagine this works best when the phone is on a hard surface but not so well if held in hand

Comment: @Joni Definitely a valid point, since users do tend to hold their phones.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think so. Screen protectors and cases are made with sensors in mind, so they don’t interfere with proximity sensors  cameras, or microphones, which I think is the only way we have to know if there’s something on the phone.

Battery cases, or lightning accessories are something else though, but I don’t think you are talking about those.

Comment: I am trying if I can get something different from 3D touch events, but it looks all data is the same with or without screen protector.....

Comment: 3DTouch registers from a specific pressure. I think it would take the user a bit more force to press the screen with a screen protector on, but 3DTouch wouldn't really care about it.